# Number of maximums in each row and more

Tags: r

My dataset contains four numerical variables X1, X2, X3, X_4 and an ID column.

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
X1 <- c(3,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4)
X2 <- c(1,2,1,3,2,2,4,1,2,4)
X3 <- c(1,1,1,3,2,3,3,2,1,4)
X4 <- c(1,4,1,1,1,4,3,1,4,4)
Mydata <- data.frame(ID, X1,X2,X3,X4)
```

I need to create two more columns: 1) Max, and 2) Var

1) Max column: For each row that has ONLY ONE maximum, I need to save this 'max' value in the Max variable. And if the
row has more than one, then the Max value should be 999.

2) Var column: For the rows with only one maximum, I need to know whether it was X1, X2, X3$, or X4.

For the above dataset, here is the output:

```
ID  X1  X2  X3  X4  Max Var
1   3   1   1   1   3   X1
2   1   2   1   4   4   X4
3   1   1   1   1   999 NA
4   1   3   3   1   999 NA
5   2   2   2   1   999 NA
6   1   2   3   4   4   X4
7   2   4   3   3   4   X2
8   1   1   2   1   2   X3
9   3   2   1   4   4   X4
10  4   4   4   4   999 NA
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could get the column names of the 'Mydata' for the maximum value in each row (excluding the 'ID' column) using `max.col` ('Var'), and the maximum value per row with `pmax` ('Max').  Create a logical index for rows that have more than one maximum value ('indx') and use it with `ifelse` to get the expected output.

```
Var <- names(Mydata[-1])[max.col(Mydata[-1])]
Max <- do.call(pmax,Mydata[-1])
indx <- rowSums(Mydata[-1]==Max)>1

transform(Mydata, Var= ifelse(indx,  NA, Var), Max=ifelse(indx,  999, Max))
```

Comment: Too fast as always. I was in a middle of writing almost identical answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know if this is the most efficient.  Perhaps, an `apply` based solution could be created without more lines.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking `apply` The problem with it is that you will need to run too many operation per line which will make it very slow I guess.

Comment: @akrun many thanks for this beautiful answer... two minutes to go to get the best answer!

Comment: @user9292 Thanks for your comments.  BTW, do you have NAs in the dataset.

Comment: I was thinking apply too... just replacing the pmax do.call with an apply is about 3 times slower  `microbenchmark({Max <- do.call(pmax,Mydata[-1])},
    {Max2 = apply(Mydata[-1], FUN = max, MARGIN = 1)})`

Answer (score 4):

Here's another possible `apply` solution

```
MyFunc <- function(x){
  Max <- max(x)
  if(sum(x == Max) > 1L) {
    Max <- 999
    Var <- NA     
    } else {
      Var <- which.max(x)
      }
  c(Max, Var)
}

Mydata[c("Max", "Var")] <- t(apply(Mydata[-1], 1, MyFunc))
#    ID X1 X2 X3 X4 Max Var
# 1   1  3  1  1  1   3   1
# 2   2  1  2  1  4   4   4
# 3   3  1  1  1  1 999  NA
# 4   4  1  3  3  1 999  NA
# 5   5  2  2  2  1 999  NA
# 6   6  1  2  3  4   4   4
# 7   7  2  4  3  3   4   2
# 8   8  1  1  2  1   2   3
# 9   9  3  2  1  4   4   4
# 10 10  4  4  4  4 999  NA
```

Answer (score 3):

I would break this down into some small steps, which may not be the most efficient but would at least give you a starting point to work from if efficiency were an issues for your real problem.

First, compute the row maxes:

```
maxs <- apply(Mydata[, -1], 1, max)

> maxs
 [1] 3 4 1 3 2 4 4 2 4 4
```

Next compute how which values in the rows equal the maximum

```
wMax <- apply(Mydata[, -1], 1, function(x) length(which(x == max(x))))
```

This gives a list, which we can `sapply()` over to get the number of values equalling the maximum:

```
nMax <- sapply(wMax, length)

> nMax
 [1] 1 1 4 2 3 1 1 1 1 4
```

Now add the `Max` & `Var` columns:

```
Mydata$Max <- ifelse(nMax > 1L, 999, maxs)
Mydata$Var <- ifelse(nMax > 1L, NA, sapply(wMax, `[[`, 1))

> Mydata
   ID X1 X2 X3 X4 Max Var
1   1  3  1  1  1   3   1
2   2  1  2  1  4   4   4
3   3  1  1  1  1 999  NA
4   4  1  3  3  1 999  NA
5   5  2  2  2  1 999  NA
6   6  1  2  3  4   4   4
7   7  2  4  3  3   4   2
8   8  1  1  2  1   2   3
9   9  3  2  1  4   4   4
10 10  4  4  4  4 999  NA
```

This isn't going to win any prizes for elegant use of the language, but it works and you can build off of it.

(That last line creating `Var` needs a little explanation: `wMax` is actually a list. We want the first element of each component of that list (because those will be the only maximums), and the `sapply()` call produces that.)

Now we can write a function that incorporates all the steps for you:

```
MaxVar <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  ## compute `max`
  maxx <- max(x, na.rm = na.rm)
  ## which equal the max
  wmax <- which(x == max(x))
  ## how many equal the max
  nmax <- length(wmax)
  ## return
  out <- if(nmax > 1L) {
    c(999, NA)
  } else {
    c(maxx, wmax)
  }
  out
}
```

And use it like this:

```
> new <- apply(Mydata[, -1], 1, MaxVar)
> new
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3    4  999  999  999    4    4    2    4   999
[2,]    1    4   NA   NA   NA    4    2    3    4    NA
> Mydata <- cbind(Mydata, Max = new[1, ], Var = new[2, ])
> Mydata
   ID X1 X2 X3 X4 Max Var
1   1  3  1  1  1   3   1
2   2  1  2  1  4   4   4
3   3  1  1  1  1 999  NA
4   4  1  3  3  1 999  NA
5   5  2  2  2  1 999  NA
6   6  1  2  3  4   4   4
7   7  2  4  3  3   4   2
8   8  1  1  2  1   2   3
9   9  3  2  1  4   4   4
10 10  4  4  4  4 999  NA
```

Again, not the most elegant or efficient of code, but it works and it's easy to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to do this using `apply`

```
Mydata$Max = apply(Mydata[,-1], 1,
function(x){ m = max(x); ifelse(m !=  max(x[duplicated(x)]), m, 999)})

Mydata$Var = apply(Mydata[,-1], 1, 
function(x){ index = which.max(x); ifelse(index != 5, names(x)[index], NA)})

#> Mydata
#ID X1 X2 X3 X4 Max  Var
#1   1  3  1  1  1   3   X1
#2   2  1  2  1  4   4   X4
#3   3  1  1  1  1 999 <NA>
#4   4  1  3  3  1 999 <NA>
#5   5  2  2  2  1 999 <NA>
#6   6  1  2  3  4   4   X4
#7   7  2  4  3  3   4   X2
#8   8  1  1  2  1   2   X3
#9   9  3  2  1  4   4   X4
#10 10  4  4  4  4 999 <NA>
```